# Different images when Zoom In and Zoom Out

Tags: php, jquery, frameworks, zooming

I wanted a zoom functionality where in when i doublclick on an image it should go inside the image

For Eg: 
I have an image of a bike.. If i double click on the tyre, it should show the tyre.. And if I double click on the tube of the tyre, it should show the tube..

I'm basically using this to display the parts and its price in my website. Something like a Catalogue.

Is this possible only in Flash??
Or is there any framework that i can use to do this??

Can we do this using css3??

Comment: yes in flash it is possible if you have core knowledge of action script. Beside that the dblclick and zoom effect also possible in html with jquery, again condition is you should have a good knowledge of HTML and jquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with `jquery`

See 28 jQuery Zoom Plugins Creating Stunning Image Effects

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-zoom.html

http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2011/10/jquery-image-zoom.html

You can pick the one you like

Comment: i was asking for this functionality.. check this link.. http://static.flabber.net/files/scale-of-the-universe-2.swf